# Unable to save data in database laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I have a problem , saving data to the database from the input form that I made. The code is running well but the form is not saving the data I input from the form to the database. Did I miss something? when I click on the button to save the info to the database, nothing seems to happen(meaning no error).

Here is my jquery:

```
var percentageSupport = "";

$('#btnSaveFinanicialSupport').on('click', function () {

    if (patientId == "") {
        alert("kindly Enter Patient Id  ")
        return false;
    }

    if ($('#currentSupport').val() == 0) {
        alert('Kindly Give Financial Support');
        return false;
    }

    var totalPayableAmount = $('#payableAmount').val();
    var currentSupportAmount = $('#currentSupport').val();


    if (currentSupportAmount > totalPayableAmount) {
        alert('Kindly Enter Correct Support Amount');
        return false;
    }
    //here to start to set data to call save service.

    var percantageSupportAmount = Math.round((currentSupportAmount / totalPayableAmount) * 100);


    var supportType = $('select.supportType').val();
    var token = supportType.split("@");
    var supportTypeId = token[0];
    var supportType = token[1];
    if (supportType == "SELECT") {
        alert('kindly Select Support Type');
        return false;
    }
    var comments = $('#comments').val();
    var orderIds = $("#tbody input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).attr("orderId");
    }).get();

    var serviceIds = $("#tbody input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).attr("serviceId");
    }).get();

    var serviceCost = $("#tbody input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).attr("price");
    }).get();

    var servicePayableAmount = $("#tbody input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).attr("payableAmount");
    }).get();

    var serviceFinancialSupport = $("#tbody input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).attr("financialSupport");
    }).get();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            patientId: patientId, supportTypeId: supportTypeId, percantageSupportAmount: percantageSupportAmount,
            comments: comments, serviceIds: serviceIds, orderIds: orderIds, servicePayableAmount: servicePayableAmount,
            serviceFinancialSupport: serviceFinancialSupport, serviceCost: serviceCost
        },
      
        url: '/saveFinancialSupport',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Financial Support Given Successfully")
            $("#tbodyy").html("");
            $("#tbody").html("");
            $('#totalAmount').val('');
            $('#totalAmount').text('');
            $('#paidAmount').val('');
            $('#paidAmount').text('');
            $('#supportamount').val('');
            $('#supportamount').text('');
            $('#comments').val('');
            $('#comments').text('');
            $('#totalamount').val('');
            $('#totalamount').text('');
            $('#totalpayable').val('');
            $('#totalpayable').text('');
        }
    });
})
```

Here is my controller:

```
 //save financial support
     public function saveFinancialSupport(Request $req){
        $output = array();
        $orderIds = $req->orderids;
        $serviceIds = $req->serviceids;
        $servicePayableAmount = $req->servicePayableAmount;
        $serviceFinancialSupport = $req->serviceids;
        $serviceCost = $req->serviceCost;
        $obj = new SessionClass();
        $array = array();
        for ($i=0; $i < count($orderIds) ; $i++) {
                    $price = $serviceCost[$i];
                    $support = ($servicePayableAmount[$i] * $req->percentageSupport)/100;
                    $array[$i] = array(
                    "financialSupport" => $support,
                    "patientId" => $req->patientId,
                    "orderId" => $orderIds[$i],
                    "supportTypeId" => $req->supportTypeId,
                    "price" => $serviceCost[$i],
                    "sign" => "+",
                    "percentageSupport" => $req->percentageSupport,
                    "comments" => $req->comments,
                    "active" => "Y",
                    "refFormNo" => "0",
                    "serviceId" => $serviceids[$i],
                    "id" => "123",
                    "locationId" => $obj->getLocationId(),
                    "orgId" => $obj->getOrgId(),
                    "sessionId" => $obj->getSessionId(),
                    "crtdBy" => $obj->getUserId(),
                    "crtdTerminalId" => "123");
         }

         $host = new HostClass();
         $obj = new SessionClass();
        $data = json_encode($array);
        $response = Http::post('127.0.0.1:9000/saveFinancialSupport', $array);
        return redirect()->back()->with('alert', 'Record Save Successfully');

    }
```

Here is my web route:

```
Route::post('saveFinancialSupport' , 'SupportController@saveFinancialSupport');
```

Here is my web route:

```
@extends('layouts.theme')
@section('content')
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="container custom-container">
        @include('patientPanel.patientPanel')

        <form method="post" action="saveFinancialSupport" id="fsform">
            @csrf
            <div class="card mb-2">
                <div class="card-body pb-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <label>From Date</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <input type="Date" name="fromDate" id="fromDate" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                placeholder="Client">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <label>To Date</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <input type="Date" name="toDate" id="toDate" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1 mt-1" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight:bold;">
                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="All Date" id="allDates">&nbsp All Dates</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1 mt-1">
                            <label>Support Limit</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <input type="text" name="supportLimit" id="supportLimit" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                value="" readonly="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1 mt-1">
                            <label>Support Given</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <input type="text" name="supportgiven" id="supportgiven" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                value="" readonly="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- //end card one -->


            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="block">
                        <div class="card-body p-0">
                            <div style="height:200px;overflow-y: auto;" class="outer">
                                <table id="tblServiceOrders" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
                                    <thead class="bg-dark">
                                        <tr class="font" style="color: white;">
                                            <th>Order Date</th>
                                            <th>Order By</th>
                                            <th>Service Name</th>
                                            <th>Cost</th>
                                            <th>Support</th>
                                            <th>Payable</th>
                                            <th>Select</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="tbody" class="rowClick">
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="collapse" id="tblSupportDetailCollapse">
                    <div class="block">
                        <div class="card-body p-0">
                            <div style="height:100px;overflow-y: auto;" class="outer">
                                <table id="supportDetail" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
                                    <thead class="bg-dark">
                                        <tr class="font" style="color: white;">
                                            <th>Order Date</th>
                                            <th>Order By</th>
                                            <th>Service Name</th>
                                            <th>Cost</th>
                                            <th>Support</th>
                                            <th>Payable</th>
                                            <th>Select</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="tbody" class="rowClick">
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- end second table -->
            <!-- here is start final calculation of financial support -->

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body pb-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <label>Total Amount</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <input type="text" name="totalAmount" id="totalAmount" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                value="" readonly="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <label>Support </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <input type="text" name="supportAmount" id="supportAmount"
                                class="form-control form-control-sm" value="" readonly="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <label>Payable</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <input type="text" name="payableAmount" id="payableAmount"
                                class="form-control form-control-sm" value="" readonly="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 mb-1">
                            <select class="form-control form-control-sm supportType" id="supportType">
                                <option value="SELECT">SELECT</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1 mb-1">
                            <select class="form-control form-control-sm percentageSupport" id="percentageSupport">
                                <option value="SELECT">SELECT</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <input type="text" name="currentSupport" id="currentSupport"
                                class="form-control form-control-sm" value="" >
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <label>Net Payable</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-1">
                            <input type="text" name="netPayable" id="netPayable" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                                value="" readonly="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- here calacualtion here  -->

            <div class="card mb-2">
                <div class="card-body forms">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-1 mb-1">
                            <label>Remarks</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-11 mb-1">
                            <input type="text" name="comments" id="comments" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- row end -->
                </div> <!-- card body forms -->
            </div> <!-- card mb-2 -->

            <div class="block border">
                <div class="card-body pt-2 pb-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary col-lg-12" id="btnSaveFinanicialSupport" style="color:white">Financial Support</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger col-lg-12" id="">Cancel Support</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary col-lg-12" id="btngenerateinvoice"
                                style="color:white">Patient Support History</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="supportDetail" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#tblSupportDetailCollapse" aria-expanded="false"
                                aria-controls="tblSupportDetailCollapse">
                                Support Detail
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('PublicCssForm/PacslinkCustomcss.min.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ url('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url('js/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url('theme/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url('OrderInvoiceJs/FinancialSupport.min.js') }}"></script>
@endsection
```

Comment: I don't see `save()` or `create()` anywhere in your controller that would actually save a record. In fact, all I see is a possible posting loop...

Comment: So....what debugging have you done? Probably _something_ happens. Does it at least submit the form? Have you checked for JS errors in the console? Have you stepped through the JS code with a debugger to see what it does? Have you seen whether the AJAX request is executed, and if so what it sends and what the response is? If that is happening, have you stepped through the PHP code with a debugger, or added some logging into it to see what it does? Narrow down the issue, please, we can't run the code for you, you need to do basic investigation before _dumping a mountain of code here_. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. See also [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue for further guidance.

Comment: Some quick observations though at a glance: `return redirect()->back()->with('alert', 'Record Save Successfully');`...you report success, but how do you know? As anyber points out, there's nowhere that any saving seems to take place, and no code which seems to actually test for success of anything.

Comment: And what is `$response = Http::post('127.0.0.1:9000/saveFinancialSupport', $array);` supposed to do? Is that where the saving actually takes place (or is supposed to)? Is this calling a controller in a different application, which happens to have the same name? If not, what is its purpose? And why aren't you examining what `$response` contains in order to know what happened as a result? Apart from the total lack of any meaningful debugging info, we also seem to be missing a big piece of relevant code and context too.

Comment: Please, pretend for a minute you are one of us, and have never seen your application or its code before, and cannot execute it because you can't see the database and so on. How would _you_ attempt to answer this question?? As you can see, people are mainly making suggestions based on some level of assumption, or are asking for clarification. This suggests the question is not in a truly answerable state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @aynber mentions in his comment to your question, you are not creating or saving a model, which is obviously the main problem here.

I see that you have this line:
`$obj = new SessionClass();` which I assume is the model you want to save, but you do nothing with it, and you also overwrite it below your loop.

First of all, you need to have fields `fillable` on that model and then either `save()` or `create()` with data.

You can see an example of it here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#inserts

Simple example:

```
class Object extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3'];
}
```

You can then use this class to do something like:

```
$obj = new Object;
$object->save([
   'data1' => 'some value',
   'data2' => 'some value',
   'data3' => 'some value',
])

// You can also do it like, which will create and save it for you.
$obj = Object::create([
   'data1' => 'some value',
   'data2' => 'some value',
   'data3' => 'some value',
]);
```

If the fields are not described in the `$fillable` array of the model, they will not be persisted to the database.